# Using Stram<T> with Async in riverpod for state management

Tags: flutter-riverpod

I am using Firebase with Flutter. Getting firebase stream from repository. In the `StateNotifier` class, using `AsyncValue` union class for state management using 'loading', 'data', and 'error' states in my `ConsumerWidget`.

My Code:

```
class MyTableNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<TableModel>> {
  final Ref ref;
  MyTableNotifier(this.ref) : super(const AsyncValue.loading());



 getMyTable(String tableId) async {
    try {
      final repo = ref.watch(tableRepoProvider);
      state = const AsyncValue.loading();

      var tbl = repo.getTable(tableId);

  state = AsyncValue.data(tbl); <-- error (The argument type Stream<TableModel> cant be assigned to the parameter type 'TableModel'
  print('i am hit');
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  state = AsyncValue.error(e.message!);
    }
  }
}
```

Error: I am getting the Stream object from the repository, however I cant find a way to use AsyncVal with Stream type object.

What I have tried:

I have tried to change the AsyncValue> type of the statenotifier to Stream but this way I lose the loading, data and error states in the AsyncUnion class.

Help:
Can please someone guide me in the right direction, where I still use the loading, data and error states with Stream objects?

Thanks